# How can I not run this command 'sudo amazon-linux-extras install -y lamp-mariadb10.2-php7.2 php7.2'?

Tags: php, wordpress, amazon-web-services, amazon-linux

I am following this tutorial: https://aws.amazon.com/getting-started/hands-on/deploy-wordpress-with-amazon-rds/?refid=dd707452-50b0-4e41-9f2b-d84c7ca273d4 in an attempt to create my own wordpress server on ec2 / rds of AWS.

However, I DO NOT want to run this line

```
sudo amazon-linux-extras install -y lamp-mariadb10.2-php7.2 php7.2
```

because wordpress does not like php7.2. This is my second time through, and the first thing I found was that I needed to upgrade php, which does not seem possible once this is installed. I could not find any way to remove this package once installed, either. But, I can't find any "updated" way of doing this. I ended up having to blow everything away and start over.

How do I get httpd to run wordpress without this?

EDIT: The package shown shows after it is installed that it has reached end of support life.

Comment: What version of PHP is required? AWS extras go as high as 8.0. `sudo amazon-linux-extras enable php8.0 ` see https://techviewleo.com/install-php-8-on-amazon-linux/ for full doc. Getting 8.1 or 8.2 is a bit more work.

Comment: The minimum recommended is php7.4 I did exactly what you show already, but I think the issue is that the php processing part is in the mariadb part of this. I don't have a lot of php experience, if you can't tell. I would think there is some common way to set up a php server. I just don't know what else is required.

Comment: @DannyEllisJr. you can try using mariadb as well like this: `lamp-mariadb10.2-php8.0`, you can use the PHP version you prefer.

Comment: @SarojShrestha, that package does not exist. I also tried lamp-maridadb10.5 because there is a mariadb10.5 but not a lamp-mariadb10.5.

Comment: @DannyEllisJr. instead of using premade package `lamp-maridadb10.5`, why not use LAMP stack individually, install `apache`, `PHP`, `mysql` I think this will have more control to you.

Comment: @SarojShrestha, that's what I'm looking for! Can you provide an answer with some links to how to install the lamp stack individually? If you'll do that, I will accept your answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To launch wordpress on amazon AWS ec2:

1. Launch the instance (ubuntu), generate key pair
2. Open ssh terminal and run following commands

```
//just update and upgrade apt repositories
sudo apt update
sudo apt upgrade

//install apache2
sudo apt install apache2 -y
sudo systemctl start apache2

//install PHP
sudo apt-get install software-properties-common
sudo add-apt-repository -y ppa:ondrej/php
sudo apt-get update

sudo apt-get install php -y

//i suppose above it installed php8.1 
//so installing all other related tophp8.1

sudo apt-get install php8.1-cli php8.1-common

//actually these extensions were used for laravel,
//so not all might needed for WordPress but you can install all of these

sudo apt-get install apache2 php8.1 libapache2-mod-php8.1 php8.1-curl php-pear php8.1-gd php8.1-dev php8.1-zip php8.1-mbstring php8.1-mysql php8.1-xml curl -y
sudo apt install -y php8.1-bcmath  php8.1-ctype
sudo apt-get install zip unzip php8.1-zip

sudo systemctl restart apache2

//enter ipaddress on browser, it should show localhost, if installed successfully

//install MySQL
sudo apt install mysql-server
sudo mysql 

//inside mysql tab
==============
ALTER USER 'root'@'localhost' IDENTIFIED BY 'NewPassword';
create database database_name;
exit;
=================

//install Wordpress 
//go to default HTML directory

cd /var/www/html

//now push file to on this directory from git, if you have it on local
// or install a new from repo
// you can consider /var/www/ as your htdocs folder in xampp

//now need to set up your DNS
// for this you can view some tutorial on `route 53` DNS hosting, you have to  allocate elastic IP address, and map your domain to this IP
```

3. let's say your domain is `sarojshrestha.com`
   Next, you need to run following commands to map a domain to `/var/www/html`

```
cd /etc/apache2/sites-available

//disable default conf
sudo a2dissite 000-default.conf 

//create new conf for your domain
sudo nano sarojshrestha.com.conf

//and paste this following:
<VirtualHost *:80>

    ServerName sarojshrestha.com
    ServerAlias www.sarojshrestha.com
    ServerAdmin admin@sarojshrestha.com

    DocumentRoot /var/www/html
    <Directory /var/www/html/>
        Options Indexes FollowSymLinks MultiViews
        AllowOverride All
        Require all granted
    </Directory>

    ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log
    CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined

</VirtualHost>

//save and exit by ctrl+s and ctrl+x
```

4. Next, enable this one.

```
sudo a2ensite sarojshrestha.com
```

Now, hit `sarojshrestha.com` on browser, you should see Wordpress setup view. Replace, `sarojshrestha.com` with your actual domain.

By the way, to install, you might need to change the permission of `/var/www/html` folder. You can let me know if you find any issues.

Comment: Very nearly perfect. I deviated a bit around installing wordpress, but otherwise this worked great! Thanks!

Comment: Happy to help you.